# Cronie Setup in Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, cronie

Here is my working crontab on debian, it runs every 5 minutes.

```
*/05 * * * * user /usr/bin/php /var/www/monitoring/cron/status.cron.php
```

I'm able to execute the script `status.cron.php` in my browser or php cli, the script works as intended.

Now I was forced to run the same script in Arch Linux, the thing is, Arch make use of systemd/timers and I am not used to it, then I heard about `cronie` and decided to give a shot, here is what I got so far:

cronie was installed and is runing, see:

```
● cronie.service - Periodic Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cronie.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-12-23 00:40:31 +07; 1 months 1 days ago
 Main PID: 631 (crond)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4620)
   Memory: 5.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cronie.service
           └─631 /usr/bin/crond -n

Jan 24 00:41:01 user-pc CROND[31933]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.minutely #Runs a cron job script every minute)
```

created a file called `monitoring` in `/etc/cron.d` directory
here is the file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
*/1 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.minutely #Runs a cron job script every minute
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly #Runs a cron job script every hour
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily #Runs a cron job script every day
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly #Runs a cron job script every week
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly #Runs a cron job script every month
```

created a new directory called `cron.minutely` in `/etc/`, then created a new file called `monstatuscron` in it, here is the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
#*/01 * * * * user /usr/bin/php /var/www/monitoring/cron/status.cron.php
#/usr/bin/php /var/www/monitoring/cron/status.cron.php
/usr/bin/php /var/www/monitoring/cron/status.cron.php
```

I guess this file should be an script as it says it Arch docs, but what type of script? shell script with instruction to run my php script? or what else?
I commented the two lines right below `#!/usr/bin/php` cause it didn't work. I got stuck at this point.

I also run the command `journalctl -xb -u cronie` to check if the job is running and I got a lot of entries like this one:

```
Jan 24 00:58:01 user-pc CROND[32175]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.minutely #Runs a cron job script every minute)
```

It seems to be running as intended.

Appreciate Any help on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) shouldn't be `#!/usr/bin/php`, but `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`. That is because Bash is the default shell for ArchLinux - and that is a shell script, calling a PHP script. Also make sure to `chmod +x cron.minutely/*.sh`, so that it can be executed. There's no need to put PHP-CLI scripts into `/var/www`, because they can run everywhere (there they could eventually be run via the PHP-SAPI and expose sensitive information).

Comment: I changed to `#!/bin/bash` but still the same results. It is a localhost, this `status.cron.php` script in /var/www/ also can be executed manually via web interface by an admin user in case cron is not working like now.

Comment: Or conversely, if you keep he `php` shebang, make sure the code in the script is valid PHP code.

Comment: That means the content of the file `/etc/cron.minutely` can be any script?

Comment: The problem is, that `run-parts` expects a directory as argument, and not a file... in theory one can tell which interpreter to use, nevertheless it is better to manage shell scripts and PHP scripts separately. The `<?php ?>` tags are only required for PHP-SAPI - but when having them in `/var/www`, they'd be served as plain-text.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, `Jan 24 02:00:01 user-pc CROND[11473]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.minutely #Runs a cron job script every minute)` - `/etc/cron.minutely` is a directory with a file called `monstatuscron` inside.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, I can run it manually without any problems.

Comment: @tripleee I will try this way.

Comment: The [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron) read: Files in `/etc/cron.minutely` are executed every minute if instructed accordingly in `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` ...

Comment: It works now, the problem was the dam shebang, I was checking the output of `journalctl` but in the application it executed as intended.
Thanks @MartinZeitler, you were right.